# Can't find variable error when using SetState following user auth

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, expo

I get the error

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 20):
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setUser
```

I am using Firebase for User Authentication in a React Native app. When the user becomes logged in, I call `setUser()`.

```
export default function App() {
    // Set an initializing state whilst Firebase connects
    const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    

    useEffect(() => {
      const subscriber = auth.onAuthStateChanged((_user) => {
        if (!_user) {
          ...
        }
        else {
          setUser(_user);
          if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
        }
      });
      return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
    },[]);
}
```

I use `user` to determine which `Stack.Screen` loads.

```
return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Group>
            { user && <Stack.Screen name="CoreTabs" component={CoreTabs} options={{ headerShown: false, }} /> }
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false, }}/>
          ...
          </Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
            ...
          </Stack.Group>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>  
    );
```

The error surfaces when I change between screens. I am guessing the auth changes on other screens could be triggering the `useEffect`, but I don't understand why setUser is being read as a variable.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another `setUser` than what you show here?

Comment: 100% sure. Did a search through all files. No other use of `setUser`.